# RSelenium browser randomly closes

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm running a scrape that takes about 600 iterations, involves a lot of scrolling and at the leisurely pace I'm going with random sleeps etc should take 8 or so hours if all goes smoothly. However, I'm seemingly randomly running into an issue where the browser window closes and the session dies. I get an error:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14417 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I've done some basic troubleshooting and can't figure out what is causing the problem. Does anyone know what could be causing this? My chromedriver and chrome are both up to date if that information helps. I'm also running through a VPN.

This is what I'm using to start the session:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

  try(driver[["server"]]$stop())

  driver <- rsDriver(verbose = TRUE
                     ,browser="chrome"               
                     ,port=free_port()
                     ,check=F)
  
  remDr <- driver[["client"]]
```

If nobody has a direct solution to the problem, could anyone think of a workaround wherein the code checks if the session has died and reinstates it?